# Unable to connect to MongoDB only from TestingModule in NestJS

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, e2e-testing

I am doing e2e test of my NestJS application, and I get following error:

```
[ExceptionHandler] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)... +1977ms
```

This is my beforeEach function, where i initialize the module:

```js
beforeEach(async () => {
  const mod = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      ConfigModule.forRoot({ isGlobal: true, load: [cfg] }),
      MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
        useFactory: async (cfg: ConfigService) => {
          return {
            uri: cfg.get("mongouri"),
          };
        },
      }),
      AccountModule,
    ],
  }).compile();

  conf = mod.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);

  app = mod.createNestApplication();
  await app.init();
});
```

What's confusing me the most, is the fact, that when i'm starting my application normally with `nest start --watch` command (In my AppModule, MongooseModule initialization is exactly the same as here), everything works just perfectly, so I suppose the problem is somewhere inside TestingModule, and I have no idea where exactly and what do I do.

Comment: Before the return of the MongooseModule print the value of cfg.get("mongouri") to check if that value is undefined

Comment: I just checked, it is defined and it is the exact uri i want to connect to @JuanRambal

Comment: Can you provide more info about the real module that you're trying to mock? I mean, the code of that module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but apparently I somehow effed up my Jest config. Removing root directory from `moduleDirectories` did actually resolve the problem.

```json
"moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    ""
],
```

to

```json
"moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
],
```

I have no idea how and why that works, would be glad to hear the reason from somebody more competent than me.

The main reason why I even added the line to Jest configuration is just because I was too lazy to change absolute paths to relative in half of my project's files.

Answer (score 0):

That's because this line.

https://github.com/nestjs/mongoose/blob/01bc29db10f92005f9acdfc7ab4eb2087cdb0387/lib/mongoose-core.module.ts#L103

```js
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
  ...

  static forRootAsync(options: MongooseModuleAsyncOptions): DynamicModule {
        ...
        return await defer(async () =>
          mongooseConnectionFactory(
            mongoose.createConnection(mongooseModuleOptions.uri as string, {
              useNewUrlParser: true,
              useUnifiedTopology: true,
              ...mongooseOptions,
            }),
        ...
  }
```

If you add `""` or `"./"` path on `moduleDirectories`, the `mongoose` module points here. https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/mongoose/index.d.ts#L78

There is no `createConnection` method, so it occurs `mongoose.createConnection is not defined` error on `mongoose.createConnection()` called.